# Как добавить символ \ в регулярное выражение

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть такая регулярка:

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-ЯÉ()-,.!&"«»';
```

А как сюда добавить символ `\`?

Comment: Экранировать? \\

Comment: @andreymal Сделал вот так var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-ЯÉ()-,.!&"«»\\'; выдал ошибку preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 44

Comment: Эм, два раза экранировать что ли? \\\\

Comment: Если $product_name_rules подставляется куда-то в регулярное выражение с квадратными скобочками, то тогда `.:_` экранировать нет смысла, а вот дефис тоже придётся экранировать дважды, чтобы он не сработал как обозначение диапазона символов `\\-`

Comment: Дефис можно не экранировать, а поставить его последним символом.